# Genexus File.Exists() don't find my image

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to check if a image on a directory exist, but the function `.Exists()` is returning false.

I defined `&File` as a File data type.

I tried:

```
&File.Source = !'c:\users\dev6\pictures\cat55.jpg'
if &File.Exists()
    GDebug('Find')
else
    GDebug('Don't find')
endif
```

`GDebug` is one procedure that make a log in a archive.
I'm only receiving "Don't find" but i have the archive cat55.jpg...

Comment: If you are using Windows, try opening a command line prompt and execute `dir c:\users\dev6\pictures\cat55.jpg` to ensure there is not a typo somewhere.

Comment: my image open normally when i try to open by the path... i think is something like permission

Comment: You can confirm if it's a permissions related issue by taking a look at the `&File.ErrCode`and `&File.ErrDescription` properties, after calling the `&File.Exists()`  method.